# Make response from API call accessible from all controllers - angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that takes the user input and post's it to my API and captures the response which happens to be the user data. That's great however I need to access the user data on the dashboard which has a different controller. I can't figure out how to abstract the API call into a service and fetch the response from the dashboard controller. Is there an easier way? The login functionality works perfect however the `res.data.user` appears inaccessible. My question is how do I make the response accessible from a diffefrent controller?

Controller (signup):

```
angular.module('app').controller('Signup', function ($scope, $http, toastr, $location, $auth) {

// Submit request to Sails.
$http.post('/api/user/email', {
  email: $scope.signupForm.email.toLowerCase(),
  password: $scope.signupForm.password
})
.then(function onSuccess(res){

  $auth.setToken(res.data.token)
  $location.path('/dashboard')
  $scope.user = res.data.user;

})
})
```

HTML (dashboard):

```
<div class="container" ng-show="isAuthenticated()" ng-controller="Dashboard">
<p>License: {{user.license}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: which router are you using? `ngRoute` or `ui-router`?

Comment: @charlietfl ui-router

Comment: If make a parent state for all states that need login, can have `resolve` on that parent state that rejects if user data not available. Then on login set that user data

Comment: @charlietfl - I'm not following... Would ngStorage be a viable solution for this?

Comment: yes, storage can be very helpful but still need to check login status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a factory or service that stores user data to pass around. Inject it in the original

```
.factory('storeData', function () {

var userData = {}; //it's empty, thats ok

function dataAll () {
return userData;
};

return dataAll;
}


.controller('Signup', function ($scope, $http, toastr, $location, $auth, ***storeData***) {
//remove *** obviously
var importedData = storeData();
```

// or storeData.dataAll() for some reason OP said this didn't work but it works in my code

```
$http.post('/api/user/email', {
  email: $scope.signupForm.email.toLowerCase(),
  password: $scope.signupForm.password
})
.then(function onSuccess(res){

  $auth.setToken(res.data.token)
  $location.path('/dashboard')
```

> will modify factory object that was returned to contain res.data.user
>   instead of blank. javascript does not make copies, but instead links
>   back to the original factory object. So changes take place on the
>   factory object.

```
importedData = res.data.user 


  $scope.user = res.data.user;

})
})
```

new controller example

```
.controller('test', function ($scope, storeData) {

console.log(storeData() + 'see if data shows up');
}
```

Comment: I like the track you're on it's just your answer is hard to understand / read. Working through it now and thank you.

Comment: Unlike other OO languages, javascript makes links not copies. So the storedData.dataAll() returns the original object file....and modifications made to it, get stored on the factory object, not a local copy. So it's easier to call stored.DataAll() on another controller. You could also use $rootScope with angular and parent controllers to share data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am getting `Unknown provider: storeDataProvider <- storeData <- Signup`

Comment: I made some syntax errors and spelling mistakes. I fixed them, please double check.

Comment: still getting `Unknown provider: storeDataProvider <- storeData <- Signup` :(

Comment: did you remove the ***? I just put them there for context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90752/discussion-between-ciscokidx-and-deek).